# gradle issue in flutter android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

i was facing problems with android studio which i can get the `SHA-1` and gradle some how doesnt exist and while trying to solve it this happen to my files in the photo and u can see there is no gradle icon please some help
this appear when i try to get `SHA-1`
could not open `cp_settings` generic class cache for settings file

tried uninstalling and installing
new windows

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're experiencing some issues with Android Studio and Gradle. To address the problem with the missing Gradle icon and the error message about the settings file, try refreshing your project or restarting Android Studio. Additionally, make sure your Gradle files are properly configured and that there are no errors in your project's build files. If the issue persists, you might need to reinstall Android Studio or check for updates to see if there are any fixes available for your specific problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).